# Estimating prediction accuracy of a Cox survival model using sbrier (R)

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

The integrated Brier score (IBS) has been suggested in a paper by Graf et al (1999) as a good measure for prediction accuracy in survival models (see e.g. [overview paper by Wiering et al.](http://www.slcmsr.net/boulesteix/papers/survival.pdf), page 23).

It was implemented in the package `ipred` as function `sbrier`. However, whereas the brier score definition obviously applies to Cox proportional hazard models, I cannot get `sbrier` to return the Brier score for a `coxph` model.

Here is the problem set up.

```
library(survival)
library(ipred)
data("DLBCL", package = "ipred")

#Fit coxph model    
smod   <- Surv(DLBCL$time, DLBCL$cens)
coxmod <- coxph(smod ~ IPI, data = DLBCL) # I just chose a significant covariate from DLBCL
```

Now I want to estimate the IBS. Following `?sbrier`

```
obj  : an object of class Surv.
pred : predicted values. Either a probability or a list of survfit objects.
```

So we have a list of survfit objects

```
sbrier(smod, list(survfit(coxmod) ))
```

or survival probabilties

```
sbrier(smod, survfit(coxmod,newdata=DLBCL)$surv )
```

The first returning

```
Error in sbrier(smod, list(survfit(coxmod))) : 
  pred must be of length(time)
```

The second

```
Error in sbrier(smod, survfit(coxmod, newdata = DLBCL)$surv) : 
  wrong dimensions of pred
```

The examples do not list a `coxph` model. Perhaps it's not supported. Otherwise, where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pec package, instead.

Example:

```
library(pec)
set.seed(18713)
library(prodlim)
library(survival)
dat=SimSurv(100)
pmodel=coxph(Surv(time,status)~X1+X2,data=dat)
perror=pec(list(Cox=pmodel),Hist(time,status)~1,data=dat)
## cumulative prediction error
crps(perror) # between min time and 1
## same thing:
ibs(perror)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(survival)
library(ipred)
data("DLBCL", package = "ipred")



smod   <- Surv(DLBCL$time, DLBCL$cens)
coxmod <- coxph(smod ~ IPI, data = DLBCL)
coxmod
Call:
coxph(formula = smod ~ IPI, data = DLBCL)
     coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z      p
IPI 0.505     1.657    0.181 2.79 0.0053
Likelihood ratio test=8.15  on 1 df, p=0.0043
n= 38, number of events= 20 
   (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

#### Only 38 observations were used . The others needed to be removed before predicting.

```
DLBCL <- DLBCL[!(is.na(DLBCL$IPI)|is.na(DLBCL$time)|is.na(DLBCL$cens)),]

pred  <- predict(coxmod)
 sbrier(smod, pred,btime=2)
```

result

```
Brier score 
  1.457241 
attr(,"time")
[1] 2
```

The btime must be specified, which means ibs can't be calculated. I have not figured it out yet.